# Is there an analogue of string landscape in condensed matter physics?

Tags: condensed-matter, effective-field-theory, string-theory-landscape

Possibly not every quantum field theory can be viewed as an effective theory of string theory, and possible effective theories are called the [landscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swampland_(physics)). It's natural to guess that something similar may happen in condensed matter physics, at least in solid state physics, where there are no adjustable parameters and possible lattice structures are restricted (on the other hand, there is only one parameter in string theory, and there is a collection of allowed false vacua). Are there some criteria about what effective theory is highly impossible to be realized in a condensed matter system?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking about real materials or abstract lattice models? (I'm assuming based on the "no adjustable parameters" bit that you mean the former.)

Comment: I'm asking about the former; actually I'm doubting whether some so-called "effective" lattice models can really be implemented in a real material, so definitely I'm not asking about abstract lattice models ;)